How to Perform Programmatic Navigation with react-router-dom v6?
I'm working on a React application and trying to implement programmatic navigation using react-router-dom v6. I want to navigate to different routes based on user interactions, such as button clicks or form submissions. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to use the useNavigate hook correctly for this purpose.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavigationExample() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    navigate('/about');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Go to About Page</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavigationExample;

I'm unsure if this is the correct approach for programmatic navigation with react-router-dom v6. Are there any best practices or common pitfalls I should be aware of? Any guidance on how to properly use useNavigate for programmatic navigation would be greatly appreciated.
I'm working on a React application and attempting to implement programmatic navigation using react-router-dom v6. I've tried using the useNavigate hook to navigate to different routes based on user interactions, such as button clicks or form submissions.
Here is the code snippet I've tried:

import React from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavigationExample() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleButtonClick = () => {

    navigate('/about');

  };

  return (

    <div>

      <h1>Home Page</h1>

      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Go to About Page</button>

    </div>

  );

}

export default NavigationExample;


I expected that clicking the button would navigate to the "/about" route, but nothing happens when I click the button. It seems like the useNavigate hook is not working as expected. Are there any additional steps or configurations I need to consider for programmatic navigation with react-router-dom v6?

Based on the code you provide there is nothing wrong with the way you use the useNavigate hook. the issue may comme from the configuration of the router of your react app based on the documentation of react router : https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router
you first if all have to configure a global router provider in you entry file generaly app.js or app .ts
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "./routes/routes";

export default const App = () => {
 <RouterProvider router={router} />
}

then in route.ts you have to create a new browser router
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
    path: "/about",
    element: <About />,
   },
]);
 export default router;

